# JOM not able to find Makefiles

Tags: qt

I am attempting to build my project with QT Creator, but I get an error with jom.exe telling me that `The system cannot find the path specified.`

The complete error is:

```
11:14:35: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\\MainMenu.exe.embed.manifest">debug\MainMenu.exe_manifest.rc
The system cannot find the path specified.
jom: C:\Users\<user>\build-MainMenu-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_OpenGL_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\MainMenu.exe] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\<user>\build-MainMenu-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_OpenGL_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
11:14:35: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project MainMenu (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 OpenGL 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
11:14:35: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

My user name is 15 characters long, making the entire path to the MakeFiles 99 and 93 characters respectively.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: 1. Check if the makefile is actually there, with proper permissions. 2. If it is, try overriding the maketool with `nmake` and verify that it'll work. If it won't, it's not a `jom` problem.

Comment: Yes, both Makefiles are present.  All accounts on this computer have full rights to the files.  I'm just starting out with QT, how do you override with nmake?

Comment: Did you replace the username with <user> in your output or is this the exact output?

Comment: In the actual run, it's the correct username.  It's set up as my real name and I didn't want it public, so I replaced it with `<user>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an antivirus ? 
jom.exe works with temporary files that, sometimes, are detected as a virus...

So, try to disable your antivir.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you haven't add the libraries correctly. If you mess with the library files adding in `project_name.pro` file, then simply remove all the lines you write to add the libraries, and right click on the project folder, click `Add library...` button, then add the libraries one by one as you want. Qt will automatically generate the pro file code to add the libraries.

When you add the libraries correctly, the code will look like this

`win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/LibFolder/ -lLibrariyName`
`else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/LibFolder/ -lLibrariyName`
`else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/LibFolder/ -lLibrariyName`

`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/LibFolder`

`DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/LibFolder`

`$$PWD` is the present working derectory, if your library files are in a different location then `$$PWD` will replace with something like `C:\LibriFileLocation`in windows and `/usr/libFileLocation` in Linux.